# How to animate process of hiding view?

Tags: android, animation

I want to create view that will hide behide other view with nice visual effect. Firstly, I look on Android developer docs and find  animatiion framework and write code like this:

```
    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, 
        Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0.0f, Animation.ABSOLUTE, -80.0f);
    animation.setDuration(200);
    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                searchContainer.startAnimation(animation);
                findViewById(R.id.explore_place_search).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
```

So I get movement when I click on the button but I want to freeze view on the last position when animation has completed. Better approach move view when user touch this element (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN). Can I ask you about how to do that or where I can read about same cases? All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of thoughts there... Animations are fairly simple in android, take a look at the api demoes: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html

Here is an example of two imageviews fading in and out on top of eachother:

```
                Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.00f, 1.00f);
                fadeIn.setDuration(1000);
                fadeIn.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {}
                });

                Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1.00f, 0.00f);
                fadeOut.setDuration(1000);
                fadeOut.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        placeholderImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                placeholderImageView.startAnimation(fadeOut);
                imageView.startAnimation(fadeIn);
```

This is done in code but animation can just as well be done with xml.